# apt-get update errors

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

I have a vServer and every time then I try to make `apt-get update` this Errors will be come in the end but why? How I can fix that?

```
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-math-biginteger
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package libjpeg62
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-psr-http-message-implementation
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-psr-log-implementation
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-seclib
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-sabre-http
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-math-biginteger
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi-backend-api-max
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi-backend-api-min
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-max
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-min
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-max
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-min
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package libjpeg62
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-max
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-min
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-max
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-min
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

Comment: Can you add the output of the command `uname -a` to your question, please?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/openstack-manuals/+bug/1511462)  this issue is actually harmless. But if you really want to fix this you have to update your `apt` version.

Comment: Can you complete yr answer with some sort of an upgrade path for `apt` ?

Comment: @Cbhihe I don't know `apt` can upgrade itself like `dnf` (`sudo dnf upgrade dnf`) or not. I could not find anything on it.